# java ee cdi: catch exception thrown by producer method

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, exception, cdi

is it possible to catch an Exception that is thrown by a producer method in Java CDI? I have following producer method

```
@Produces
public User getLoggedInUser() throws UserNotLoggedInException {
    if(...){
        throw new UserNotLoggedInException();
    }
    User user = ... 
    ...
    return user;
}
```

and i want to inject the user object somewhere. I cannot write the method like this:

```
private void doSomethingWithUser(){
    try {
        User loggedInUser = user.get(); // throws exception
    } catch (UserNotLoggedInException e){  // Compiler compains
        ...
    }
}
```

As the compiler says that the `UserNotLoggedInException` is not thrown in any method. If i catch a generic `Exception`, everything works fine. Is there a more elegant solution to this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As stated in CDI spec (http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.0/html/contexts.html#contextual), exception thrown when instantiating a bean should be unchecked exception (extends `RunTimeException`), I guess it's not the case of your `UserNotLoggedInException` since complier checked it ;).

If you change your `UserNotLoggedInException` to make it extends `RunTimeException` it should work

Anyway I always find it more elegant to avoid dealing with exception. You could do something like :

```
@Produces
public User getLoggedInUser() throws UserNotLoggedInException {
    if(...){
        return null;
    }
    User user = ... 
    ...
    return user;
}
```

and check the null value later.

```
private void doSomethingWithUser(){
    if (user != null)
        User loggedInUser = user.get(); // throws exception

}
```

This work only if your user is in @Dependent scope.

The best approach in my opinion would be to avoid declaring your user as a bean but rather as a field in a bean. So this bean would always exist while its user field would be null when not logged in and not null when logged in.

Null beans are a bit weird.

Comment: thanks for your input. I rather not have null returns, as I tend to forget to check them. In this case however, it would make no difference since the compiler wouldn't complain about an unchecked exception either. I guess we will have to live with that. Thanks!

Comment: You could use a Null object (User.NULL) instaed of null or use guavas Optional.class.